# unable to download the file using java

Tags: java, upload, download

I've just implemented a jsp program to upload a file into my PC folder. The path of this folder is `E:\UploadedFile`. The file name i want to download is `assad.xml` (the one i have just uploaded). This is how i am trying to download it. Please check my code and correct me if i am wrong.

```
<%@page import="java.io.*,java.net.*"%>


 <%
  System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "192.168.1.10");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
 try {
    /*
     * Get a connection to the URL and start up
     * a buffered reader.
     */
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();  
    System.out.println("Connecting to URL...\n");  
    URL url = new URL("E://UploadedFiles/");
    url.openConnection();
    InputStream reader = url.openStream();  
    /*
     * Setup a buffered file writer to write
     * out what we read from the website.

     */
    FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream("E:/assad.xml");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[153600]; // Buffer for 150K blocks at a time
    int totalBytesRead = 0;
    int bytesRead = 0;
    System.out.println("Reading ZIP file 150KB blocks at a time.\n");  

    while ((bytesRead = reader.read(buffer)) > 0){  
       writer.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
       buffer = new byte[153600];
       totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
    }  
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();  

    System.out.println("Done. " + (new Integer(totalBytesRead).toString()) + " bytes
  read (" + 
           (new Long(endTime - startTime).toString())+ " millseconds).\n");
    writer.close();
    reader.close();
 }catch (MalformedURLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
 catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
 }

 %>
```

The name of the folder in which i have just uploaded my file is **UploadedFiles** and its in **E: drive**. The name of the file i want to download is **assad.xml**. Its available inside this folder.

Comment: new FileOutputStream("E:/assad.xml"); or E:\UploadedFile\assad.xml ??

Comment: File upload code is working well. But the code above for downloading the file is not working with my problem.

Comment: @Renjith.. in my PC, the file path is E:\UploadedFile\assad.xml. What changes should i make in above code to make it right. I mean the above code is working perfectly well if i want to download stuff from internet. But its not working in this particular way.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you inverted the filename, like Renjith said. For a more consistent API take a look at: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/index.html

Comment: Item Jr... I just want to make some modifications in my above code. It works when i download anything from internet. But its not downloading the data available in E:\UploadedFiles\assad.xml in my PC

Comment: Thanks. I've figured out myself